# Replacing values in pands df (not Nan) with the column sum except first two cols

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

**Update: I mixed up the axis. Thats why my question seems weired.
This is the new input data:**

give following data:

```
data = {'Org': ['Tom', 'Kelly', 'Rick', 'Dave','Sara','Liz'],
'A': ['NaN', 1, 1, 1, 'NaN', 'NaN'],
'B': [1, 1, 1, 1, 'NaN', 1],
'C': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
'D': ['NaN', 'NaN', 1, 'NaN', 1, 'NaN'],
'E': [1, 1, 1, 1, 'NaN', 1],
'F': ['NaN', 1, 1, 1, 'NaN', 1]}
```

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I want to sum the columns except the first two and then replace the values not NaN with the sum the column results:

the result should like this:

```
data = {'Org': ['Tom', 'Kelly', 'Rick', 'Dave','Sara','Liz'],
'A': ['NaN', 1, 1, 1, 'NaN', 'NaN'],
'B': [5, 5, 5, 5, 'NaN', 5],
'C': [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6],
'D': ['NaN', 'NaN', 2, 'NaN', 2, 'NaN'],
'E': [5, 5, 5, 5, 'Nan', 5],
'F': ['NaN',4, 4, 4, 'NaN', 4]}
```

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

I tried:

```
column_sums = df.iloc[:, 2:].sum()
for column in iloc[:, 2:].columns:
     df[column] = column_sums[column]
```

But that replaces me all values.

Is there a smooth solution for that possible?

Thanks

Comment: it's unclear why the first **row** is unchanged

Comment: also in your expected result you did sum to the second column, did you mean to only not apply it to the first column instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build as mask, [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) and modify in place after broadcasting the sum:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read data, ensure NaNs are valid (not strings)
df = pd.DataFrame(data).replace('NaN', float('nan'))

# number of initial columns to skip
N = 2

# build boolean mask
m = df.notna()
m.iloc[:, :N] = False

# sum, broadcast values, replace in dataframe
df[m] = np.repeat(m.sum(0).reindex(df.columns).to_numpy()[None],
                  df.shape[0], axis=0)
```

Output:

```
     Org    A    B  C    D  E    F
0    Tom  NaN  5.0  6  NaN  6  NaN
1  Kelly  1.0  5.0  6  NaN  6  4.0
2   Rick  1.0  5.0  6  2.0  6  4.0
3   Dave  1.0  5.0  6  NaN  6  4.0
4   Sara  NaN  NaN  6  2.0  6  NaN
5    Liz  NaN  5.0  6  NaN  6  4.0
```

Intermediate `m`:

```
     Org      A      B     C      D     E      F
0  False  False   True  True  False  True  False
1  False  False   True  True  False  True   True
2  False  False   True  True   True  True   True
3  False  False   True  True  False  True   True
4  False  False  False  True   True  True  False
5  False  False   True  True  False  True   True
```

Comment: This does not match OPs required output

Comment: @TA well, OP says conflicting things in the question, that said the logic is the same, build a mask of the values to sum, then broadcast based on the mask ;)

Comment: I appologize.. i asked with the wrong input data. Can you update your advice according to my new data?

Comment: @hadji btw, don't use `'NaN'` strings, rather go with `np.nan` to keep homogeneous dtypes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) with select all columns without first `N` columns in [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
import numpy as np

#If NaNs are strings convert them to missing values NaNs
df = df.replace('NaN', np.nan)

N = 2
df.update(df.iloc[:, N:].mask(df.iloc[:,N:].notna(), 
          df.iloc[:, N:].sum(numeric_only=True, axis=1), axis=0))
print (df)
  Org  Tom  Kelly  Rick  Dave  Sara  Liz
0   A  NaN    4.0     4   4.0     4  NaN
1   B  1.0    4.0     4   NaN     4  4.0
2   C  1.0    5.0     5   5.0     5  5.0
3   D  1.0    4.0     4   NaN     4  4.0
4   E  NaN    NaN     2   2.0     2  NaN
5   F  NaN    4.0     4   NaN     4  4.0
```

Comment: I appologize.. i asked with the wrong input data. Can you update your advice according to my new data?

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df.columns[2:]] = (
    df.iloc[:, 2:]
    .replace({'NaN': float('nan')})
    .pipe(lambda x: x.mul(x.sum()))
)
```

df

```
     Org    A    B    C    D    E    F
0    Tom  NaN  5.0  6.0  NaN  5.0  NaN
1  Kelly    1  5.0  6.0  NaN  5.0  4.0
2   Rick    1  5.0  6.0  2.0  5.0  4.0
3   Dave    1  5.0  6.0  NaN  5.0  4.0
4   Sara  NaN  NaN  6.0  2.0  NaN  NaN
5    Liz  NaN  5.0  6.0  NaN  5.0  4.0
```

Comment: I appologize.. i asked with the wrong input data. Can you update your advice according to my new data?